# ¿Cómo puedo crear requirements.txt para mi proyecto?

Tags: python, virtualenv

necesito crear el archivo de "requirements.txt" para mi página web hecha con flask.
Mi problema es que cuando abro el cmd en la carpeta de mi proyecto y escribo:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Me generea muchísimos, os mostraré unos pocos

```
aiodns==1.2.0
aiohttp==3.5.4
altgraph==0.17
app==0.0.1
appdirs==1.4.3
arrow==0.15.5
asgiref==3.2.5
assert==0.1.0
astroid==2.3.3
```

Ninguno de estos están en mi proyecto, me gustaría saber si hay algún comando como por ejemplo

```
pip freeze index.py > requirements.txt
```

Alguna manera de indicar el nombre de mi archivo y que escoja solo sus librerias.
Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer el correr pip desde el virtual environment de tu proyecto. Y si tu proyecto no tiene un *venv* ... ahora ya sabes por qué es interesante tenerlo! Si utilizas el mismo entorno de python para todo, cuando intentes hacer cosas como pip freeze, te recogerá todos los paquetes instalados de manera general en tu python, además de que `pip freeze` busca también las dependencias de CADA una de tus dependencias.... Por supuesto siempre puedes hacer el requirements.txt a mano unicamente con las dependencias que quieras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ampliando el comentariod de @Benito-B. Te pueden ocurrir dos cosas:

### 1. Que no estés usando entornos virtuales.

En tal caso es siempre muy recomendable usarlos, sobre todo si estás creando proyectos con Flask. **Un entorno virtual lo que hace es generar espacios de trabajo con distintos paquetes y dependencias**. Esto principalmente nos evita que haya problemas entre paquetes y que tengamos de una forma más ordenada los distintos proyectos en los que estamos trabajando.

**Ademas** cuando quieras realizar exportaciones de tus proyectos, por ejemplo a servidores en la nube, será mucho más sencillo **"clonar"** el entorno en el que has trabajado en local.

Puedes instalar pipenv con el siguiente comando:

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

E instalar los paquetes de tu proyecto con (por ejemplo Flask):

```
pipenv install flask
```

Te dejo un enlace que explica varios comandos y como funciona [aquí.](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Pero no solo existe `pipenv`, también tienes los entornos de `conda`, `venv` etc. Por lo que hay distintas opciones (en el fondo todas hacen lo mismo).

### 2. Que tengas un entorno virtual, pero no sepas como funcionan los paquetes.

En este caso, estarías usando un entorno virtual, pero lo que necesitas saber es que cuando usas por ejemplo `Flask`. Este módulo, no es un paquete creado de cero, **¡A su vez está usando otros paquetes!**

`Flask` tiene las siguientes dependencias: `Werkzeug`, `Jinja`, `MarkupSafe`, `ItsDangerous`, `Click`, además de otras dependencias opcionales

Si tu te encuentras alguno de estos paquetes puedes pensar que no los has instalado, pero cuando instalaste `Flask`, se instalaron automaticamente para que `Flask` pueda funcionar.

Comment: De acuerdo, ese era mi problema, mi duda actual es cuando he creado ya un entorno virtual, ¿Cómo corro mi proyecto desde mi entorno virtual?

Comment: En el link que te refiero en la respuesta, aparece **basic usage** donde te dice como activar el entorno usando ```source venv/bin/activate``` donde ```venv``` es el nombre de tu entorno. A partir de ahí corres tu proyecto igual que cuando no tenías entorno.

Answer (score -2):

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```